# How to tell git that two commits are the same?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-rewrite-history

Currently I have two branches, name it A and B:

```
    B1-...many dirty checkouts...-B2
   /
--O-A1-A2-......................-A3
```

Currently, B2 and A3 are the same (`git diff A B` gives an empty output).

Now the problem is, that this state was reached by partial checkouts from A. I.e. many times a `git checkout -- dir1 dir2`... happened and not a `git merge`.

Simply merging B to A totally craps A, what is impossible.

I don't want to lose B's history.

Somehow I should tell git, that a `git merge A` on the branch B shouldn't do anything.

Of course I could simply replace B2 with A3, but in this case I would lose B's history.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If there are no diffs, why is merging a problem?

Comment: Are you trying to keep B history and replace A = B history ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The "dirty checkout" means that some `git checkout -- dir1`, `git checkout -- dir2` and similar have happened (and some other merges between them, too). Now A3 and B2 are exactly the same, this is why the diff is empty, but git doesn't know it.

Comment: It sounds like there is some confusion between working directory and commits here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, the working directories were perfectly okay (I never made a commit, merge, etc without a perfectly synced working directory).

Comment: @sajibkhan I don't want to lose B's history (this is why I can't use `git replace`), but if it gets new entries it is not a problem.

Comment: If you lose A's history, any problem ? I mean, delete A & create new-A from B.

Comment: @sajibkhan No, it is the most impossible (it is the upstream for which I work).

Comment: I think that default merge strategy (recursive) failed and produced garbage because you have several ***best common ancestors*** for 3-way merge (effect of criss-cross merges between branches, see `git merge-base --help` for details). To check it you can run `git merge-base --all B2 A3` - if you receive several hashes, it means criss-cross situation, and merge might produce garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might help here is a different *strategy* in `git merge` via the `-s` option, like `ours`:

```
   ours
       This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the
       merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively
       ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be
       used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note
       that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive
       merge strategy.
```

It sounds like this might just basically take the given branch you are on as-is, and create a commit with the additional heads as additional parents; i.e. what it seems you are trying to do.

Comment: As I see, it probably doesn't overwrite B's history, am I right?

Comment: Nothing overwrites history in git, other than ... non-fast-forward changes.

Comment: This would be the way to go, but there's a bit of mystery here if the graph in the original question is correct, because `git merge` works by diffing the merge base against the two tip commits. If the two tip commits `B2` and `A3` are identical, and there is only the one merge base `O`, then the two diffs will be identical and the merge result will be the same tree as in both `B2` and `A3`.

Comment: @torek Yes; that would be the case under a naive three-way-merge that doesn't look at any of the deltas in between, like `cvs up -j rev1 -j rev2`

Comment: @Kaz: that's what Git does. Other VCSes must look at each rev for renames and/or to combine all the deltas, but Git's design skips all of that.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution:

1. I checkout B with a `git checkout B`.
2. I merge A into B with a `git merge A`. Now B is locally in a crap state.
3. But now I do a directory checkout with `git checkout remotes/origin/B -- .`. This restores B into its desired state.
4. Now pushing up B (`git push --all`) will update the merge arrows as needed.

Comment: If somebody has a better solution, I am ready to accept that.

Comment: *"Now B is locally in a crap state."* -- why? If `diff A3 B2` doesn't show any difference then `B` points to the merge commit that is identical (as content) to `A3` and `B2`. Maybe your working tree was not in a clean state before starting?

Comment: @axiac It was in clean state, but many changes between B1 and B2 happened with `git merge`, while other changes happened with `git checkout A -- dir1` and similar. The result is that many commits are seen by the git as unmerged, thus a `git merge B` on A causes git to merge them again. It results the crapped state of A (probably it is only luck that I don't have also merge conflicts).